# Synchronized, join, and thread safety

Tags: java, thread-safety

I have read through other examples, but do not understand why this code with the commented out t.join() does not always have the end value 5000 for count, but when the code is commented in, count always is 5000 at the end. But why? I thought that the static lock object can only be owned by one thread at a time and when it is owned that the other threads have to wait until it is released. So I do not understand why join() is necessary and what exactly is happening.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyClass implements Runnable {
    private static int count = 0;
    private static Object lock = new Object();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ArrayList<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5000; i++)
            threads.add(new Thread(new MyClass()));

        for (Thread t : threads)
            t.start();
        // for (Thread t : threads)
        //     t.join();

        System.out.println("Total count = " + MyClass.getCount());
    }

    public void run() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            count++;
        }
    }

    public static int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: You simply print the result before all threads are finished. `join` waits for the threads to finish.

Comment: Also, because you don't join, you don't guarantee a happens-before between the writes in the threads and read in the main thread. So, even if some threads have finished by the time you print, you're not guaranteed to see the updated count.

Comment: Just in case you didn't know: `t.join()` _waits_ until thread `t` is finished.  (In fact, that's the _only_ thing that `t.join()` does.) So, if you comment out the `t.join()` calls from your main thread, it's like the comments above say: The main thread will print out the "Total count" without waiting for the other threads to finish.